# qTip2 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

My code used to work until I dunno what i changed, I started everything from scratch yet it still doesn't show the tooltip, can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?
or even better, is there any other (easier) way to implement a tooltip ?

```
<html>
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.qtip.css" />    
<title>My site</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">ZA</a>  
    <div id="jj" style="display: none;">HHHHHHH</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('a').qtip({
        content: {
        text: $('#jj') // Add .clone() if you don't want the matched elements to be removed, but simply copied
    }
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why dont you add the scripts in the head section, have you tried looking into a debugging tool for errors, like firebug in fire fox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you missing the onload?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a').qtip({
        content: {
            text: $('#jj') 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Edit: the code above most definitely works, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Razor/Z447D/)

Make sure your qtip.js and qtip.css are loaded and recent

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('a').qtip({
    content: $('#jj').text()
});
```

Or do what the comment said and clone the element -- you'll probably have to show it explicitly:

```
$('a').qtip({
   content: {
      text: $('#jj').clone().show()
   }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work either ! even when I use " text 'bla bla bla' " it doesn't work either (without quotes ofc)

Answer (score 1):

you need to put your qtip javascript inside a document ready.

```
$(function() {
    $('a').qtip({
        content: {
             text: $('#jj').clone()
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

two things that you can try

1. move the scripts to your head section
2. wrap the javascript/jquery code inside the `ready` handler

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       $('a').qtip({
          content: {
          text: $('#jj') // Add .clone() if you don't want the matched elements to be removed, but simply copied
        }
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: goto http://getfirebug.com/ install this plugin after the installation is complete restart the FireFox and load the page where you are having the problem hit `f12` it will bring up the console, rest you can explore ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/qTip/jquery.qtip.css" />    
<title>My site</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">ZA</a>  
    <div id="jj" style="display: none;">HHHHHHH</div> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/qTip/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('a').qtip({
                content: {
                    text: $('#jj')
                }
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The original poster asked what was wrong with his/her code. Could you update your answer and explain what was wrong please.